# Base64 to gallery cordova plugin not saving image to gallery

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new with web programming and I am testing the Base64 to gallery plugin to see if I can save an image to an android gallery.

I have the following code in which I provided the actual base64 string. When I run the function on my android, I get a success message, ‘Saved image to gallery’. But when I check my gallery, I cannot see any new images. And I have checked any other folders but I can not find the image.

Storage permissions are already accepted on the app.

```
import { Base64ToGallery } from '@ionic-native/base64-to-gallery/ngx';

constructor(private base64ToGallery: Base64ToGallery) { }






downloadImage(){

const imgBASE64String = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD//gAMQXBwbGVNYXJrCv/............. '

  this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(imgBASE64String, {prefix: '_img', mediaScanner: false}).then(
    res => alert('Saved image to gallery '),
    err => alert('Error saving image to gallery ')
  );

}
```

Comment: can you show Error messege in ` err`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting mediascanner to true;